# APL Enclose with Axis: How does ⊂[n]A work?

Tags: multidimensional-array, apl

First some code:

```
A ← 2 2 2 ⍴ ⍳8
A
 0 1
 2 3

 4 5
 6 7

⊂[0]A
 0 4  1 5
 2 6  3 7
```

I can imagine enclosing on the first axis to mean sub-slicing the array on its depth, yielding `[[0 1][2 3]]` & `[[4 5][6 7]]` or I could see it meaning sub-slicing on columns, yielding `[[0 2][4 6]]` & `[[1 3][5 7]]`. But of course it doesn't do either. (`⊂[1]A` does the second, what operation would do the first?)

What is the underlying algorithm that `⊂[axis]array` is using to split the array? I've drawn out several tables to see if I could build an intuition for it, but I've not been able to and I've not been able to find this information in the documentation I've looked at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll use one-based indexing – you can set ⎕IO if you want to type along.

The dimension given in the axis specification is the one that will be affected. That is, if you enclose over the *n*th dimension, the rank will decrease, as the shape of the result will be the original shape without the *n*th dimension.

```
      ⍴a ← 2 3 4⍴⍬
2 3 4
      ⍴⊂[1]a
3 4
      ⍴⊂[2]a
2 4
      ⍴⊂[3]a
2 3
```

Now, the arrays along that *n*th dimension will keep their places on the retained dimensions, but as a scalar containing (i.e. *enclosing*) them, yielding a nested array:

```
      a ← 2 2 2⍴⍳8
      a
1 2
3 4

5 6
7 8
      ⊂[1]a
┌→──┐ ┌→──┐
│1 5│ │2 6│
└───┘ └───┘
┌→──┐ ┌→──┐
│3 7│ │4 8│
└───┘ └───┘
```

> What is the underlying algorithm that `⊂[axis]array` is using to
>   split the array? I've drawn out several tables to see if I could build
>   an intuition for it, but I've not been able to and I've not been able
>   to find this information in the documentation I've looked at.

For your example, a simple intuition could be to imagine two translucent sheets with the tables printed on them. You place them behind each other, slightly skewed. Then, imagine what would be projected to a wall behind them if you put a light source before them. That projected, flat table with two values in each cell is your result.

> I can imagine enclosing on the first axis to mean sub-slicing the array on it's depth, yielding [[0 1][2 3]] & [[4 5][6 7]] or I could
>   see it meaning sub-slicing on columns, yielding [[0 2][4 6]] & [[1
>   3][5 7]]. But of course it doesn't do either. (`⊂[1]A` does the
>   second,

It's not just sub-slicing – enclosing returns a nested array (except for simple scalars). I either misunderstand your notation, or the following is not clear:

```
      1 2 3
1 2 3
      ⍴1 2 3
3               ⍝ rank 1, i.e. a vector

      ≡⍴1 2 3
1               ⍝ depth 1, i.e. a non-nested array

      ⊂1 2 3
┌→────┐
│1 2 3│
└─────┘
      ⍴⊂1 2 3   ⍝ rank 0, i.e. a scalar
      ≡⊂1 2 3
2               ⍝ depth >1, i.e. a nested array
```

> what operation would do the first?)

You can enclose along a set of dimensions:

```
    ⊂[2 3]a
┌→──┐ ┌→──┐
↓1 2│ ↓5 6│
│3 4│ │7 8│
└───┘ └───┘
```

But, as explained above for `Z ← ⊂[X]R`, `⍴⍴Z ←→ (⍴⍴R)-⍴⍴X`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think the key insights I was missing was that it can take multiple axes and that it would return a rho-1 array of vectors rather than a vector of rho-1 arrays. What I'd have guessed [0] [1] & [2] do are in fact what [1 2] [0 2] & [0 1] do. Really should have checked the shape of the output instead of assuming `ngn` would visually distinguish the two cases.

Comment: Glad it helped. I havent used NGN much, so I'm not sure if it can display the boxes. Try looking for something like `]boxing` or `⎕display`. It really helps learning about this stuff.

Comment: NGN APL uses origin zero ( []IO 0 ) exclusively, so be sure to subract one from all axis specification ( ⊂[1 2]a instead of ⊂[2 3]a ) accordingly.